# What user is a web server's daemon?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, daemon, bitnami

On my web server, if I do `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>`, it returns `daemon`.

On my site I upload files, and it says permission is not granted for this user. What user or group is `daemon` on a web server?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the configuration of the system. I am assuming that you have a flavour of Unix and therefore you need to look at `/etc/passed` and `/etc/group` to get an answer. Also look at the configuration file for the server. In the case of Apache it will be `httpd.conf` and that location is configurable.

**EDIT**

References for you to look at

1. [passwd](http://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd)
2. [group](http://linux.die.net/man/5/group)
3. [chgrp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chgrp)
4. [chmod](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)
5. [chown](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown)

Comment: `root:x:0` is the first one, then `daemon:x:1`. What is this telling me?

Comment: @DonnyP - Please read the references that I have given to understand file permissions in the Unix file system.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `httpd.conf` for the user and group. This might be `daemon:daemon`.

You could either use `chmod` to change access to the directory or change the user of the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to do the following:

```
ps aux | grep -i httpd
```

That should list the account that start the Apache process.